# JdbcTemplate throws java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbctemplate

```
String query = "Select count(*) from product where date_added in (?)";

Object[] params = {dates}; //dates is a list of java.sql.Date

Long productCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, params, Long.class);
```

Last line throws:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between java.util.ArrayList
>   and JAVA_OBJECT while querying the database with IN clause

Already tried using **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate**, it was asking for quotes within the list, which can cause sql injection. To overcome that using jdbcTemplate.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove the [] from Object[] params. a List is an Object, but it isn't an array of Objects

Comment: I doubt that's the case, the queryForObject function expects an array of Objects as an argument.

Comment: you yourself said that the result is a 'List'.

Comment: 'dates' is a list but the 'params' has to be an array of Object. Let's say if I add one more where clause as manufacturer then I'll have to pass 2 values in the 'params' array. i.e. Object[] params = {dates, manufacturer}

Comment: If this is a list, and you need an array, have you tried dates.ToArray()?

Comment: and that is not syntactical correct in Java. you can iterate over the list, or do an 'toArray' or something similar, but you can't directly assign a List to an array of Objects

Comment: @WepOn the params object has to be an array not the list of dates. The collection of date has to be an implementation of the List interface.

Comment: @StuItuske when passing a collection in the query parameters in this particular case jdbc expects an implementation of List.

Answer (score 1):

You need a parameter source:

```
Set<Integer> ids = ...;

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);

List<Foo> foo = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IN (:ids)", 
parameters, getRowMapper());
```

This only works if getJdbcTemplate() returns an instance of type NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Also make sure you capture your result into a list.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I tried this fix. But it again throws java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword ')'. According to my research it expects single quotes within the list which is not a very good approach.

Comment: @faisalpathan, have you tried removing brackets around `:ids`?

Comment: yes, when i removed the brackets it threw the same error with different error message 'Incorrect syntax near 'and'.'